# ffmpeg: Saving RTSP stream with overlapping segments

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an RTSP stream and I need to segment it with 2s segments with 1s overlaps.

i.e.

```
t(s): 0----1----2----3----4----5----6----7----8----9----10---->

vids: |--1.mp4--|--3.mp4--|--5.mp4--|--7.mp4--|--9.mp4--|
           |--2.mp4--|--4.mp4--|--6.mp4--|--8.mp4--|
```

I can split to 2s segments, every 2 seconds, but I can't see how I can split to 2s segments every one second.

So far I have used the below:

```
ffmpeg \
-i rtsp://192.168.1.124:8553/unicast \
-c copy -flags +global_header \
-f segment \
-segment_time 2 \
-segment_format_options movflags=+faststart \
-reset_timestamps 1 \
%d.mp4 \
```

The approach I was thinking was to copy the stream, delay by 1s and then segment that separately but this seems wasteful and there's no way to guarantee the overlap.

Any ideas?

Comment: would be interested why the downvote here. There's literally nothing on this from what I could find anywhere on stack or google.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a bunch of stuff, including inbuilt `tee` filter as well as the `split` complex filter and trying to apply `-muxdelay 1`.

However, the best and most reliable performance turned out to be to pipe the output stream to two separate instances of ffmpeg (inefficient I know):

```
ffmpeg \
    -i rtsp://10.10.128.213:8553/unicast \
    -f nut - | tee >(ffmpeg -y -i - -f nut -c copy -f segment -segment_time 2 -reset_timestamps 1 $VID_DIR/test_1_%d.mp4) \
               >(ffmpeg -y -itsoffset 1 -i - -f nut -c copy -f segment -segment_time 2 -reset_timestamps 1 $VID_DIR/test_2_%d.mp4) \
         > /dev/null
```

All approaches except this one caused the segmentation to be wildly uneven.